# Is it possible to use the virtual device of Bluestacks or AVD of Android Studio in Geny Motion?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, bluestacks, virtual-device-manager

I develop android apps in my Windows 8 system with the help of Android Studio. Currently I test the apps using either Bluestacks or the android virtual device that is available in Android Studio. The AVD has virtual devices including Android 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.2, 4.0, 4.0.3, 4.1.2, and 4.4. Also Bluestacks runs on Android 4.1.2.

Recently I heard that Geny Motion is the fastest Android emulator. So I downloaded its newest version and installed it(also Virtual Box is installed). When I opened Geny Motion it said to add a virtual device. So I selected one device from the list and moved to next page. There it starts to download(a file of 147 MB). I can't download such a large file since my internet connection is too slow. Then I thought of using any of the virtual devices of either Bluestacks or Android Studio in Geny Motion. But I don't know whether its possible or not.

Can I use any of the virtual device of Bluestacks or Android Studio in Geny Motion ? If possible, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genymotion virtual devices are x86 virtual machines (VM) that run using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). The Genymotion launcher is just a wrapper around VirtualBox that also simulates various things about an actual device like GPS, tilting, etc.

Bluestacks and the ARM devices you see under AVD are not virtual machines. They are emulators that translate ARM instructions to x86 and that is why they are slower. Note that an x86 AVD will be slightly better in terms of speed.

So the bottom line is that you cannot do what you are asking because AVDs and Bluestacks are fundamentally different technologies than Genymotion's VMs.

Maybe you could find a hotspot somewhere to download a few Genymotion virtual devices?